# C++ Matrix-Chain-Order / Can't get desired output

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, matrix

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     double m[7][7]; //2d dimension array m
     int s[7][7]; //2d dimension array s
     int p[7] = {30,35,15,5,10,20,25}; //array p to store numbers

     int j;
     double q;

     int n = 5;

    for(int i = 1; i != n; ++i) //initialize m[1][1], m[2][2], ... to zero
        m[i][i] = 0;
    for(int l = 2; l != n; ++l) // performing the algorithm 
    {
        for(int i = 1; i != (n-l+1); ++i)
        {
            j = i + (l-1);
            m[i][j] = numeric_limits<double>::max(); // find the max
            for(int k = i; k != (j-1); ++k)
            {
                q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1]*p[k]*p[j];
                if(q < m[i][j])
                {
                    m[i][j] = q;
                    s[i][j] = k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test below:

```
    for(int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        {
            // print the m[i][j] to test the output
            cout << "m[" << i << "][" << j << "] " << " = " << m[i][j] << endl;;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing a matrix chain order, the output(my test case) should have values after performing the algorithm. But it's all zero like the picture. For example, m[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QADGb.png)[2] should be 30*35*15 = 15750.

[image: my output]

Comment: In your algorithm section `i` starts from 1 and `m[0][...]`, `s[0][...]` are never assigned to.

Comment: yeah. I changed that, but my program got an error after changing.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing for C arrays start at `0`, not `1`.

Change

```
for(int i = 1; i != n; ++i)
    m[i][i] = 0;
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    m[i][i] = 0;
```

Change

```
for(int l = 2; l != n; ++l)
{
    for(int i = 1; i != (n-l+1); ++i)
```

to

```
for(int l = 1; l != n; ++l)
// Start from 1 instead of 2
{
    for(int i = 0; i != (n-l+1); ++i)
    // Start from 0 instead of 1
```

**Update**

It's not clear what your algorithm is but the line

```
for(int k = i; k != (j-1); ++k)
```

seems to be a problem. When you enter the loop, you have:

```
l = 1
i = 0
j = 0
```

You initialize `k` to `i`, i.e. to `0`. Hence, the conditional `k != (j-1)` is never true and the loop runs for ever until you reach some sort of limit -- most likely creating overflow/underflow of floating point numbers.

Changing that line:

```
for(int k = i; k < (j-1); ++k)
```

will let your program run but I don't know whether that is the correct logic for your program.

Comment: Thank you, after changing that, my program quit unexpectedly. Could you take a moment see whats going on here?

Comment: Yeah my program can run now. Thank you, but the logic of my algorithm should be correct because I performed it refers to "Introduction of Algorithms"

Comment: @XIAODI, try to rethink the logic in terms of `0` based indexing of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing some of your for loop boolean statements from 
 "(integer) != (integer)" to "(integer) <= (integer)" depending on the circumstances. For example, in the for loops after the performing algorithm step you have:

`for(int i = 1; i != (n-l+1); ++i)` equivalent to `for(int i = 1; i < (n-l+1); i++)`

but the correct for loop for the algorithm is:

`for(i=1;i<=n-l+1;i++)`

also in this algorithm `n` is the number of matrices being multiplied and `int p[]` holds the dimensions. If there are `n` dimensions, you should have `n-1` matrices.

also in the end
`m[1][n-1]` holds the minimum number of multiplications for the matrix chain.

GeeksforGeeks does a great job of explaining how the algorithm works and they use a similar algorithm to yours. Take a look if your still interested:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-8-matrix-chain-multiplication/